# class="input-group" de bootstrap 4 no funciona correctamente con form_with de rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

Cuando edito un registro de la tabla movements (modelo Movement), altero un campo cualquiera y al dar submit del formulario no funciona; si a continuación recargo la pagina, sí me permite hacer submit correctamente.
Si en vez de utilizar la clase  de Bootstrap "input-group", utilizo la clase "form-group" funciona correctamente. Agradezco quien pueda orientarme para poder utilizar la clase "inut-group" pues el estilo de esta es muy superior a la clase "input-group".
A continuación muestro un fragmento del código de la vista:

```html
    <div class="container  p-3 my-3 border">
      <%= form_with(model: movement, local: true) do |form| %>
        <% if movement.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(movement.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this movement from being saved:</h2>
    
            <ul>
              <% movement.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <%= message %>>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        .
        .
        .
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Monto</span>
          </div>
          <%= form.text_field :amount, {class:'form-control'}%>
        </div>  
        .
        .
        . 
        <div class="input-group">
          <%= form.submit "Enter" ,{class:"btn btn-primary"} %>
        </div>
    
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: y no puedes usar ambos? algo como `class="input-group form-group"`. Hay algún javascript involucrado en el envío de tu formulario y que de alguna forma dependa de las clases `form-group`? porque no hay razón aparente que un cambio estético modifique el envío del formulario. Hay algún error en la consola de tu explorador? puedes agregar a tu pregunta los logs de enviar el formulario con una y otra clase?

Comment: @Alter Lagos, probe class="input-group form-group" y no funciono.

Comment: Ya ok, ¿pero algo más de retroalimentación como para poder ayudarte? te hice varias preguntas

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu atención @Alter Lagos, con tus preguntas, indague y pude resolver:
Como no soy muy experiente en formular preguntas en stackoverflow, paso dos cosas:
1)Al intentar mostrar la consola con una y otra clase como me preguntaste me di cuenta que me habia confundido y no funcionaba ni para "input-group" ni para "form-group"
2) Como al formular la pregunta omití una parte de la vista para que me aceptara el codigo , que me decia que era muy largo, donde muestro un grid. Probe de eliminar  la etiqueta  y reacomode y listo, funciono.

```
  <form> <- Elimine esta etiqueta y reacomode
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col p-3 my-3 border">
          Movimiento(s):
        </div>
        <div class="col p-3 my-3 border bg-primary text-white">
          DEBE
        </div>
        <div class="col p-3 my-3 border bg-primary text-white">
          HABER
        </div>
      
      </div>
      <% movement.movement_rules.each do |m| %>
          <% if m.account_id == movement.account_id%>
            <% @cr_db = m.cr_db %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col p-3 my-3 border">
              <%= m.account.name %>
            </div>
            <div class="col p-3 my-3 border">
              <%= m.cr_db == -1? movement.amount : ''%>
            </div>
            <div class="col p-3 my-3 border">
              <%= m.cr_db == 1? movement.amount : ''%>
            </div>
          </div>        
      <% end %>
    </div>
```